# What's the best practice in using if/else as a substitute for try/catch or vice versa?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the advantage of using try {} catch {} versus if {} else {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651619/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-try-catch-versus-if-else)

I'd like to know whether, generally speaking, it's better to use a try/catch construct or to try to prevent this exception by (excessive?) use of if/else. Example: should I catch a FileNotFoundException, or should I test and try to find the file first.

What would be the best approach?

Comment: Neither, a for loop is the best...

Comment: It's generally a good idea to avoid using try/catch as a substitute for proper logic.

Comment: if / else is for testing a condition and executing different code branches based on the outcome during regular operation. try / catch is for error handling, that is, take care of things that might go wrong although they normally shouldn't.

Comment: Maybe we should be a bit nicer in our judgments to first-timers, to not put them off? Ok, maybe not a good, or not a real question, but give someone the possibility to rephrase and help in that process.

Comment: Following up on my own suggestion, I rewrote @user406659's question. This is my view of his question and I believe it is (now) a very genuine and correct question, that's found in about every programming textbook and worthy of a good answer ;-)

Comment: @Abel: you have completely rewritten the question based on your guess about the OP's knowledge and intention. I suggest that if this question better represents the OP's intention that they create a new question with this text. I agree that, as phrased now, this is a valid question. As originally presented, the question was very vague, and it was answered multiple times with more detail than provided by the question.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651619/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-try-catch-versus-if-else . Also, this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/328976/thorough-use-of-if-statements-or-try-catch-blocks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are totally different. They are not interchangeable, and which is appropriate is determined by the requirement and context.

**EDIT:** This answer is based on the original, unedited question. The original, in it's entirety was:

> PHP : if/else vs try/catch
>
> which is better

Comment: Actually, that depends on your point-of-view and the interpretation of the "question". Many textbooks suggest if/else as an alternative to try/catch: i.e., prevent the error, don't catch exceptions unless you really need to and are capable of recovering state and let real exceptions fire.

Answer (score 2):

They have different purposes. It depends on the context. There is no *better*.

I suggest you read about [`Exceptions`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) and the [`if`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)-[`else`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php) statement.

Comment: They have different purposes indeed, but try/catch is often a warning for code-smell and should be rewritten as if/else instead to correct program flow and allow input to be filtered. Most exceptions should be thrown, not caught and signify that input or conditions are beyond what was expected.

Comment: @Abel: As I said, it depends on the context. Generally speaking you cannot say that one is *better* than the other.

Answer (score 2):

Rule of thumb: don't use try/catch for controlling program flow, just use it to catch errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't really understand what's if/else and try/catch.